# Crystal Reports: How do I list Table A and Table B EXCLUSIVELY in 1 report?

Tags: crystal-reports, left-join

**Apology:**
I've been experimenting with something for a while but I'm not trained in relational databases so I don't even know the language to use when trying to search for an answer.

**Table Descriptions:**

- Table A - List of Clients
- Table B - Client Orders under $100
- Table C - Client Orders Over $100

**Background:**
I want to make a report that lists EVERY client.  Some clients have entries in B and C, some have only B, some have only C (And some have none!).  I want my report to list a client (A), and then each B if they have B's, and then each C if they have C's.  I'd like the B's and C's to be in different columns (I think they have to be.)

**Problem:**
I've tried using all sorts of joins that I could do and the closest I've gotten is:

- A is Left Outer Joined (Enforced From) to B
- A is also Left Outer Joined (Enforced From) to C

**Result:**
For each change in B, it's listing every C.  I.e. if a client has 5 orders in B, and 10 orders in C, my report lists the same B 5 times in the B column and then each C once in the C column.  Then it moves onto the next B in the B column (Repeating itself for each C -- etc).  This client should have 15 rows, but it currently makes 50.

**Question:** What join am I supposed to use?  I don't understand any sort of explanation of joins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think subreports may be  your friend here. You group your report by clients from Table A, then create 2 detail sections (a, b) and in Detail A you put a subreport that uses Table B (linked to client in table a) and shows the orders under $100 and in Detail B you put a subreport that uses table C (also linked to client in table a) that shows orders over $100.

Let me know if that makes sense,

Chris

Comment: Makes perfect sense really.  I explained my situation to a coworker and we were really confused then we realized that the problem isn't the linkages or joins.  It's the STRUCTURE of the entire report.  So I'm going to rebuild it from Scratch (Again :P) using SubReports.  Do they *HAVE* to be on different detail lines though?  Just for my own edufication.  Thanks!

Comment: When I do that then I get a listing, for each grouped client, of all orders under $100 and all orders over $100 regardless of the client-group the detail is appearing in.  Please advise?

Comment: Tom, since I'm not familiar with the table structures, you may have to experiment a little. So I just whipped up a little report and tried different scenarios. Try moving your subreports into the group footers (create 2 - a and b) instead of the detail sections. Also keep in mind that the subreports are just like regular reports, so it matters where you put the fields in the subreport. Putting the field you want to display in the detail section should give you all the records you want to see. If you want, I'm available for chat.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Chris.  I didn't know about, in main design view, to right click on the sub report and then use the 'change subreport links' feature to help filter it down.  Now I'm running into other issues but the other issues are so not covered by this subject line, haha.  I'm going to continue to play with the report myself and if I can't figure it out by Tuesday of next week I'm going to post another topic (And PM you the link in case you're interested in it -- no stress of course)

Thanks so much! VERY Helpful!

Comment: Tom, glad you are making progress! I'd be more than happy to help again if you get stuck, so don't hesitate to message me. I just advised another user on an issue and suggested to check the SAP User Guide. The guide for CR 2011 can be found here http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/cr2011/en/xi4_cr_usergde_en.pdf and most of it can be applied to other versions. Keep it as a resource and maybe you find it useful! Cheers, Chris